# Change Publisher Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've used Visual Studio Express 2012 to make a simple program, but I am having trouble changing the publisher. I can go to project > properties and change the assembly information, but it does not work. Whenever I publish the clickonce application it still shows the publisher as the old information.

Where do I go to change the Publisher information?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After digging around a bit more, I've discovered the answer.

Go to Project > Properties > Publish Tab > and click on **Options** button under **Install Mode and Settings**.

From there you can customize all the information that shows up when you publish your app.

Comment: How to do this in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Can anny tell me how to do this in visual studio 2018

Answer (score 2):

in Visual Studio 2013, Right click on the project, select property, select Publish tab, click on Options button, select Description, then Publisher Name field, done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project -> Properties -> Publish Tab -> and click on Options button ->Select Description -> Publisher Name field